# Head cutaway animation - possible?

Tags: animation

I've got a possible job coming up for our university for the language department where they'd like a cutaway of a head to see how the mouth and tongue work with word sounds. Kind of like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gsgv1m1a0Sc&index=3&list=PL5FCB12D7F83D2133 but in 3d so that the camera can rotate around the head but keep that simple cutaway look (ie solid walls and empty space not like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPEBlP2cbIQ&index=4&list=PL5FCB12D7F83D2133 since it's way too busy in look). I know the camera clipping plane kind of does this but doesn't keep that walled look.

Not sure how to approach this, any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a large hidden cube cover half the head. Then apply a Boolean modifier to the head using the cube to 'subtract' the part of the head you want cut away.

Just make sure the head has a high polycount so it doesn't distort noticeably much.

Comment: That just might work Sminch04, I tried it with a sphere and cube (with a solidify modifier on the sphere) and it seemed to work well, especially when animating the cube moving around.

Comment: Hmm tried it with the BlenRig model and the boolean works to a point, if I move the cube closer to the front of the face then the boolean stops working see images...http://twistedpancreas.com/3d/character/cutaway_001.jpg http://twistedpancreas.com/3d/character/cutaway_002.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You could set a background image and trace the contours using extrusion modelling (I startet with a plane).

[image]

After that you would add a few [*Shape Keys*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Techs/Shape/Shape_Keys) for all animated parts:

[image]

Add key frames of the Shape Key's values <kbd>RMB</kbd> with mouse over the value slider.

Quick result:

[image]

To finish you would extrude the flat model and perhaps add a bevel modifier.

Comment: Thanks stacker, I'm after a more 3d rather than 2d look though, ie I can rotate around the head and still have that cutaway look. Sminch04 below seems to have the answer I'm after though, but thanks for the reply.